# WhatsApp Integration with Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, whatsapp

We have created Journey for WhatsApp messages, but we have faced an issue that messages didn't come to customers when we use Data Extension as Entry Source.
Contacts in DE are Opted-In.

It works for contacts when we use Inbound Chat as Entry Source.
Kindly provide a solution if you faced it as well.